# If 4 + 8 = 12 then why are my bootstrap grids still spilling over the edge of the page?

Tags: html, css

When making a very basic HTML page using Bootstrap 4 the size of the page is always going beyond the width of the page leaving a horizontal scroll. How do I prevent this from happening?

I have a attempted setting the width to 100% at every section I can think, as well as changing the column sizes to a value that is less than 12.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="background-color: rgb(129, 35, 101);">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body style="background-color: rgb(50, 66, 119);">
    <div class="row" style="background-color: rgb(50, 119, 67);">
      <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: rgb(119, 50, 50);">
        asdf
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color: rgb(110, 110, 87);">
        adjsfhiul
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Expected: the sizing of the page is 100%.
Actual: the sizing of the page is slightly larger than 100%.

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nu78ovp1/3/

Comment: You need to always include the boostrap container class. This is what sets the width. Rows must be wrapped in the container tag https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Where do I include this? I have tried inside, outside, and on the same line as the row class.

Comment: It has to wrap the rows. The rows have **negative margin** to override the containers padding. - http://jsfiddle.net/vo4radL2/

Comment: is there a way to prevent the padding along the sides of the columns when contained in a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap class of row is what is causing your issue, rows in bootstrap have a negative margin, since their intent is to be in a wrapper .container or container-fluid class.

If you want 100% width you need to use container-fluid, this is described in the grid documentation for bootstrap. The below code includes the container class you are missing

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row" style="background-color: rgb(50, 119, 67);">
      <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: rgb(119, 50, 50);">
        asdf
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color: rgb(110, 110, 87);">
        adjsfhiul
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this answers your question please mark as answer kindly to help others in the future. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `container` around your rows, like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="background-color: rgb(50, 119, 67);">
      <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: rgb(119, 50, 50);">
        asdf
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color: rgb(110, 110, 87);">
        adjsfhiul
      </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

See the examples in the [documentation here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).

Comment: When I do this the content becomes centered and leaves large padding on the sides, how do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

```
     <div class="container">    
       <div class="row" style="background-color: rgb(50, 119, 67);">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: rgb(119, 50, 50);">
          asdf
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color: rgb(110, 110, 87);">
        adjsfhiul
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```